# How to stop anchor links that are going to another page from jumping to top of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I'm having an issue when a link with an anchor link to another page is clicked, it goes to the new page to where it's supposed to for a brief second then jumps to the top of the page. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is doing this and/or how to fix it. I've tried to the JS files out for testing and there's no luck.

I'm just using the following code for the links:

```
    <a href="/about-us/certifications.htm#pics" >
```

and on the page it's going to, I'm using:

```
    <div id="pics"></div>
```

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems like an expected behaviour since most probably ``pics`` is at the top of the page?

Comment: So I click on a link. Does it actually go to a different page or is it on the same page that references an Id?

Comment: Yes, when you click on the link you go to a different page, and it goes to where the ID is for a brief sec then jumps to the top of that new page. I have multiple links like this that are going from the homepage to a certifications page and they all do this.

Comment: Well you could simply get the `Id` by using JS's `window.location`, parse it for the `id` (www.mywebsite.com#myId), then after the page load, use the `scrollIntoView()` method.